# Is it possible to call from a number to another number in twilio ? Neither of them being a twilio number

Tags: node.js, twilio

Lets say my twilio number is 'lmn'
I want to use twilio to call from 'abc' to 'xyz'
is it possible ?
If yes, What do I use from twilio to achieve this ... An example or git would be good too

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you own the number 'abc' in your example, then you can [add it as a verified number to your account](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio) and then use it as the caller ID, as if it was a Twilio number, when making outbound calls.

If you don't have access to number 'abc' then you won't be able to do this. Twilio enforces this so that users of the API can't abuse other people's numbers.

Comment: Thanks,
But can i actualy speak to a person on the call . In the tutorials all I could see are make and recieve calls for programmable voice. 

Is there any way to make regular calls on button click in an app or browser ; which will connect the call to the twilio number or any other number to make a conversation.

Comment: Yeah, to make calls from an app or browser you need to combine [Twilio Client JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) or the [Programmable Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk) with [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) and [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) to forward the calls on to a real device.